# $\sigma$-algebra intuition

Tags: measure-theory

So, i am trying to learn measure theory, for applications in probability theory. However, i am having some issues fully understanding the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra.

I am working with the following definition of a $\sigma$-algebra:

- Definition: Let $\Omega \ne \emptyset$. Then $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if

  - (i) $ \Omega \in \mathcal{B} $
  - (ii) if $B \in \mathcal{B}$, then $B^c \in \mathcal{B}$
  - (iii) If $B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n \in \mathcal{B}$

I do not fully understand what is going on in (iii). My intuition would say, that it should mean "If a set is in the sigma-algebra, then every possible union you could make with other sets in the sigma-algebra, is also in the sigma-algebra", is this correct? Just looking at the notation i would think that it means that the union of all sets in the sigma-algebra, should also be in the sigma-algebra, but that would just return $\Omega$ as in (i), so that cannot be correct?

Comment: (iii) says any countable union of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra (this union could be $\Omega$ or a subset of $\Omega$) is in the $\sigma$-algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @J. W. Tanner in the comments, the third criterion states that any countable union of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra is included. However, it is possible that no countable union of sets includes $\Omega$ itself. That is why we need the first criterion.

Comment: Thank you for you reply (and to everyone else), just to be sure, it means that any possible combination of unions you could possibly make, is also in the sigma-algebra? I guess i am a bit confused because of the infinity symbol, which makes me think that you must union all the countable sets, but that is not the case, right?

Comment: The union of any countable (including finite) set of $B$s within $\mathcal{B}$ is also in $\mathcal{B}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, for example, if $\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}$  is in the sigma-algebra, then by (iii) $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$ (and others) are also in the sigma-algebra or is it just $\{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: Yup, you're right. $\{a, b\}$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra as well.

Comment: Thank you! As for an example of when no countable unions of sets includes $\Omega$ itself, could that just be if $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and then it would not be possible to union all the real numbers and return $\Omega$ ?

Comment: No problem!

You have to be a bit careful with the precise statement. The implication is only required in one direction by the definition. If you have some countable number of sets, the union of those is necessarily in the algebra. However, it may be possible to have a set in the algebra that is not the countable union of any other sets in the algebra. I'm actually not aware of a specific example where this is the case, but it might be worth trying to come up with an example to further your understanding.

Comment: I guess a trivial counterexample would be the smallest possible sigma-algebra on any non-empty set $X$, the one containing only two sets, $X$ itself and the empty set. No countable union of copies of the empty set will result in the full set $X$. Thanks for this discussion, by the way -- it's helped my understanding as well!

Comment: I don't quite understand the trivial counterexample. How does it make sense to take unions of the empty set? In (iii) is it not $B_n$ not referring to different sets in $\mathcal{B}$? Also, as for why we need (i), if we just put the empty set in the sigma algebra, we will get $\Omega$ by (ii), so that cannot be an example of where we need (iii) to get $\Omega$, right?

Comment: I should have phrased that more clearly, sorry. I mentioned union because technically the definition mentions a union. A union of a set with itself any number of times is just itself, though -- nothing changes. All it comes down to is "the empty set is not equal to $X$ because $X$ is nonempty by definition".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your final question.

Answer (score 2):

The key-word which is not written in the definition is *countable*. A $\sigma-$algebra is intuitively a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ which is stable by *countable* "operations" (such as union, intersection and complementary) on its elements.